# How to access Json return value in popup in jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, model-view-controller

This is my Json function. Using doAjax function i access the value from controller and i gives me the value.

```
    function doAjax(type, url, data, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: type,
        url: url,
        data: data,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {          
            callback(data);           
        },
        failure: function (errMsg) {
            alert(errMsg);
        }
    });
}
```

here is my jquery code on button click. when i use debugger it have the values.

```
 $('.btn-setting').click(function () {       
    var data = "";
    doAjax("GET", "/Dashboard/OrderDetails/", data, function (result) {
        data = result;
        for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            var Html = "<ul><li><span>Name</span></li><li>??Name??</li></ul><ul><li><span>AirCraft Type</span></li><li>??AirCraftType??</li></ul>;
            Html = Html.replace("??Name??", data.Title + " " + data.FirstName + " " + data.LastName);
            Html = Html.replace("??AirCraftType??", data.AirCraftType);             
        }
    });
});
```

and here is my div and i want to show my json value in div popup.

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-body">

    </div>
</div>
```

So please help me to get the values on popup.
Thanks in advance

Comment: get id of div and bind ul in div..var `divID=document.getElementById('myModel');divID.appendChild(html);`

Comment: @debin, `appendChild` will not work as `html` is a string containing `tags`, `appendChild` expects DOM object as an argument..

Comment: So may b only `append()` only works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you want to put the content inside modal-body,

using jquery:

```
$('.modal-body').html('html string')
```

using javascript:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('modal-body')[0].innerHTML='html string'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

`success: function (data) { 
    $('.modal-body').dialog();
}`

or  you can append data

Answer (score 0):

var data = [
{title:'tt', FirstName:'name first', LastName:'last name', AirCraftType:'Air Craft'},
{title:'tt1',FirstName:'name first1',LastName:'last name1',AirCraftType:'Air Craft 1'}
];

```
    var Html = "";
    $(data).each(function(i, value){
      Html = Html+ here your code ;
        //here you get value.title ,value.FirstName ...
    });
    $('div.modal-body', $('#myModal')).html(Html);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the open function to load your AJAX result in your dialog.

```
$('.btn-setting').click(function ()
     $("#myModal").dialog({
                    title: 'Dialog Title',
                    autoOpen: false,
                    resizable: true,
                    height: 350,
                    width: '550px',
                    show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
                    modal: true,
                    draggable: true,
                    open: function (event, ui) {

                        $.ajax({
                            url: url //Your AJAX call URL,
                            cache: false,
                            context: this,
                            success: function (result) {
                                $(this).html(result);
                            }
                        });


                    },
                    close: function (event, ui) {
                        }
                    }
                });
                });
```